# HTTP proxy in C, recv() doesn't block?

Tags: c, http, proxy, blocking, recv

I tryied to traceback the behaviour and made up this minimal code to illustrate the problem.

What I try to do is to have a persistent connection with the client(*browser*) indefinetely. The idea is that the program waits for the client to request a page and then sends a static page back.

```
int main(){

   // Set-up proxy and wait for 1 user
   int sock;
   proxy_listen(&sock, DEFAULT_PORT, 1);
   printf("Proxy has started..\n");
   puts("Waiting for user to connect..");
   int sock_user = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);
   printf("User connected.\n");


   while (1){

      // Receive client's request
      char buff[1000];
      int got = recv(sock_user, buff, sizeof(buff), 0); // IT WON'T BLOCK HERE
      printf("Client sent bytes: %d\n", got);


char *resp="\HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\
Content-Length: 68\r\n\
Connection: close\r\n\r\n\
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><p>Got it!</p></body></html>\r\n";


      // Send response
      int sent = send(sock_user, resp, strlen(resp), 0);
      printf("Proxy sent bytes: %d\n", sent);

   }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Proxy has started..
Waiting for user to connect..
User connected.
Client sent bytes: 1000
Proxy sent bytes: 145
Client sent bytes: 416
Proxy sent bytes: 145
Client sent bytes: 0
Proxy sent bytes: 145
Client sent bytes: 0
```

**The problem is that the loop doesn't pause on recv** but instead goes on and on and eventually the program stops. Why is that?

Setting ***close*** to ***keep-alive*** in the response seems to solve this. I assume the server side has closed the connection after the first response. If that is the case, shouldn't *recv()* give me an error? Why does it give back 0 if I want it to block if there is zero data  in the socket?

Comment: You should check the return value of recv. -1 will mean an error occurred

Comment: I do. It gives back 0 all the time.

Comment: 'Check' doesn't mean just print it out. The code has to behave differently. Have you considered reading the documentation?

Comment: You're right. I've read the read() documentation and thought the behaviour was similar. Non-the-less I still don't get how I can keep a persistent connection.

Comment: The behaviour *is* similar to `read(),` identical in fact, but you still have to close at end of stream.

Answer (score 1):

`recv()` returns a value which you are completely ignoring:

- 0, end of stream: close the socket and exit the read loop.
- -1: error: unless `errno` is `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` the connection is hosed: close the socket and exit the read loop.

Comment: But as I mentioned, I want to keep a persistent connection with the user.

Comment: You can't 'have a persistent connection with the user' after he has closed his end, which is what zero means.